# MSVCR90.DLL Error When Trying to run pykml module in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, python-2.7, kml, msvcr90.dll

I am new to python and plan on using it with pykml to create KML files for Google Earth. I have succesfully installed the dependecies(lxml-2.3-py2.7-win32.egg) and the pykml package(pykml-0.1.0-py2.7.egg) itself using easy_install.

In the python interpreter I can import lxml and pykml without issue, but when I try importing pykml."any module" I get an error that says:

***python.exe - Unable to Locate Component**
-This application has failed to start because MSVCR90.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.*

After getting this I downloaded the MSVCR90.dll and placed it in my \Lib\site-package folder and got the following error:

***Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library***
*- Runtime Error!
- Program: C:\hp\bin\Python\python.exe
-R6034
-An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more information.*

Anyone with experience using pykml on Windows please help!!!

Thanks!

Comment: How did you find and install MSVCR90.DLL?  You should be installing the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 (SP1) Redistributable Package".

Comment: Msvcr90.dll must be installed in the Windows side-by-side cache.  You'll need an installer, you can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368